# Issue with GormEntity in Micronaut 3.0.3

Tags: entity, grails-orm, micronaut, micronaut-data, micronaut-rest

I have a simple micronaut 3.0.3 application built with hibernate-gorm.

I get the following error when attempting to send a GET request like this `http://localhost:8080/?commentId=1`

```
Failed to convert argument [command] for value [null] due to: Specified value [1] is not of the correct type: class java.lang.Long (through reference chain: com.example.PostCommand[\"commentId\"])
```

This code worked in Micronaut version 2.5.12. I searched the migration guide about this but could not find any mentions about anything changing in this department.

PostCommand:

```
package com.example

import grails.gorm.annotation.Entity
import org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity

@Entity
class PostCommand implements GormEntity<PostCommand> {

    String title
    String content
    Long commentId

    void setCommentId(Long commentId) {
        this.commentId = commentId
    }

    void setCommentId(String commentId) {
        this.commentId = Long.valueOf(commentId)
    }
}
```

PostContoller:

```
package com.example

import io.micronaut.http.HttpRequest
import io.micronaut.http.HttpResponse
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Controller
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Get

@Controller('/')
class PostController {

    @Get('{?command*}')
    HttpResponse search(HttpRequest request, PostCommand command){
        HttpResponse.ok()
    }
}
```

When removing all setters or just the setter for the string type, it works.

Here is a [github](https://github.com/SilverLiivamagi/gorm-hibernate-demo) link for anyone interested.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: I tested this with Spock in Micronaut 3.0.2, controller and command in Java, but without GormEntity, test passed. I believe you should consider using a clean view model for passing data to your controller.

Comment: @RoarS. Currently, rewriting all my domain objects is something I'm trying to prevent from happening. I feel that upgrading from 2.5.12 to 3.0.2 should have not broken the GormEntity functionality in this way. Could this be considered a bug in the framework itself?

Comment: Why is it that you want both `void setCommentId(String commentId)` and `void setCommentId(Long commentId)` in your entity?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown So that empty value`s cannot be passed in.

Comment: "So that empty values cannot be passed in." - having overloaded setters like that does not prevent empty values.  An empty String or `null` could be passed to `void setCommentId(String commentId)` and `null` could be passed in to `setCommentId(Long commentId)`.